# Colon Ideals and Associated Primes

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Is the following statement true?
If A is a Noetherian local ring with unique maximal ideal M, Let I be an ideal in A and x be an element s.t $x$ is not in any of the associated primes of I. Then we have to show $[I:x]=I$

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=A/I$. Then, the set of zero-divisors of $R$ is the union of the associated primes of $R$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is an associated prime of $I$ if and only if $\mathfrak{p}/I$ is an associated prime of $R$. Can you prove it from there? I've included the remainder of the proof below as a spoiler.

> Now suppose $z \in (I:_A x)\setminus I$. Then $z+I \in (0:_R (x+I))\setminus I$, i.e. $(z+I)(x+I)=(zx)+I=0$ is a product of nonzero elements in $R$ which give zero. Thus $x+I$ is a zero-divisor on $R$ and so $x \in \mathfrak{p}$ for some associated prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $I$. Contrapositively, if $x$ is not in an associated prime of $I$, then $I:_A x = I$. To see the converse, if $I:_A x = I$, then $0:_R (x+I)=0$, i.e. $x+I$ is not a zero divisor on $R$ since there is no nonzero element $z+I$ of $R$ so that $(x+I)(z+I)=0$. Thus no associated prime of $I$ can contain $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $I \subset (I : x)$ is always true. Only the reverse inclusion is to be shown.

Consider a reduced primary decomposition of $I$ (exists since $R$ is Noetherian):

$$I = Q_1 \cap \cdots \cap Q_n.$$
Note that the associated primes of $I$ are precisely $\sqrt{Q_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{Q_n}$.

Suppose that $y \in (I : x)$. Then, $xy \in I$, i.e., $xy$ is in every $Q_i$. Since $x \notin \sqrt{Q_i}$, the definition of being primary implies that $y \in Q_i$ for all $i$.
Thus, $y \in I$, as desired.